# Hosting WordPress subdomain on AWS

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I am new to AWS I am looking for some advice.

I have an Angular website hosted on AWS- EC2 instance. Now, I am planning to create a WordPress blog as a subdomain for the website . Do I need to create a new EC2 instance for subdomain or do I need to create only new hosted zone route S53 considering its a WordPress blog.

Comment: You already have WP running, and only want subdomain for it?

Comment: @Marcin Nope. I don't have WP running. My main site is Angular. For subdomain I want to use WP.

Comment: You have to run wordpress on a server *somewhere*. If you want to run it on EC2, then yes you probably need to create another EC2 instance. If you want to run it on a hosted service like wordpress.com, then all you need to do in your AWS account is create a new CNAME record in Route53. You don't need a new hosted zone for each subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is create a new prebuild Wordpress instance (Wordpress by bitnami, you can find it on the marketplace) and just assign a subdomain to the Wordpress instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on the same EC2 server you will need to use a reverse proxy server such as nginx to do so and then point the subdomain to same IP and nginx will take care of the routing

Else you will have to create a new Ec2 instance and point it to the subdomain whichever seems easier to you